# List all AWS AMI names through CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-ami

I want to write a script that prints out all the AMIs created before (or after) a certain date.  However, I am really struggling to do this so any help is sincerely appreciated.

I don't have much now, but this is what I have so far:

```
aws ec2 describe-images > c:\ami_names.txt
```

Any tips on how to filter out just for the AMIs created before a certain date?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's an example that queries for all images created after April 1st, 2016:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --query 'Images[?CreationDate>=`2016-04-01`][]'
```

I believe you should be able to expand on that example to get everything you need.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to filter the response

The command to get the AMIs created before a particular date,

```
aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --output json | jq '.Images[] | select(.CreationDate<'$GET_AMI') | {ImageId}' | jq --raw-output '.ImageId'))
```

This just gives the list of AMI-ids.

Remove `| jq --raw-output '.ImageId'))` if you need the json format.

Remove  `| {ImageId}` if you need all the attributes.